# Passing Previous / Calling / Referrer URL from view to controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have course and pages controllers and views. Each of them have edit / details actions. The list of pages is displayed on the course view in both Edit and details mode. There's a "Back" button on page view that must take the user to the calling page. Below are the two sample urls, both of which will list pages with edit / details buttons :

- root/edit/courses/course-url
- root/details/courses/course-url

I way i found to work with this is using "Referer" header Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(). But i also read that the browser can block sending this header and also it can be easily tampered. Please suggest a way to send the referer Url from the view.

```
<a href="/Topics/@CourseModel.Url/@PageModel.Url">Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you will send it as query parameter?

`<a href="/Topics/@CourseModel.Url/@PageModel.Url?backUrl=@yourBackUrlHere">Details</a>`

Comment: That's a valid solution, but the long url doesn't look good from user's perspective. Is there any elegant way to achieve that ?

Comment: You can use some type of codifier (like an enum derived from int) and then the link will be shorter. Second opinion is to use POST request with hidden inputs as a parameters.